# Deserializar json vetor em Dart/Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Estou tentando deserializar este vetor json `[{"i":737,"n":1}]` mas não estou conseguindo pegar as variaveis "i" e "n".

Classe para deserializar

```
class PortasAbertas {
  int i;
  int n;

  PortasAbertas({this.i, this.n});

  PortasAbertas.fromJson(Map<int, dynamic> json) {
    i = json[i];
    n = json[n];
  }

  Map<int, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<int, dynamic> data = new Map<int, dynamic>();
    data[i] = this.i;
    data[n] = this.n;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Objeto que estou usando para deserializar

```
 if (endereco == "portasabertas") {
     PortasAbertas objeto = new PortasAbertas.fromJson(responseJson);
      if (objeto.n == "[]"){
        _msg = ("Nenhuma porta esta aberta");
      } else {
        _msg = ("Portas abertas ${objeto.n}");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de como você pode fazer

```
class Service extends Entity{
  int           id;
  int           idUser;
  DateTime      startDate;
  DateTime      endDate;
  String        title;
  String        subtitle;
  String        description;
  double        price;
  int           ranking;

  dynamic toClass(Map<String, dynamic>  data){
    id          = data["id"];
    idUser      = data["iduser"];
    startDate   = DateTime.parse(data["startdate"]);
    endDate     = (data["enddate"]=="null") ? DateTime.parse(data["enddate"]) : null;
    image       = data["image"];
    title       = data["title"];
    subtitle    = data["subtitle"];
    description = data["description"];
    price       = double.parse(data["price"]??0);
    ranking     = 0;

    return this;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON(){

    return {
      // "id"          : "$id",
      "idUser"      : "$idUser",    
      "startDate"   : "$startDate",          
      "endDate"     : "$endDate",            
      "image"       : "$image",             
      "title"       : "$title",     
      "subtitle"    : "$subtitle",       
      "description" : "$description",       
      "price"       : "$price",             
      "ranking"     : ranking,
    };
  }  
}
```

*Obs.: Esse é um trecho de uma classe que utilizo em meu projeto*

***Explicação***

O JSON retorna sempre um conjunto de CHAVE : VALOR onde a CHAVE sempre é uma `String`, logo para você buscar o dado de uma CHAVE você faz da seguinte forma

```
variavel = json["CHAVE"];
```

Este seu método está de certa forma errado, pois o parâmetro que ele recebe não condiz com a estrutura do JSON

```
  PortasAbertas.fromJson(Map<int, dynamic> json) {
    i = json[i];
    n = json[n];
  }
```

O certo é você criar o parâmetro da seguinte forma

```
Map<String, dynamic> json
```

Dessa forma ficaria certo

```
  PortasAbertas.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    i = json["i"];
    n = json["n"];
  }
```

**Editado**

Criei esse exemplo, ve se te atende, pois como você está recebendo um array de objetos, acredito que você poderá receber dados de mais de uma porta...

```
import 'dart:convert';

/*Aqui é sua classe*/
class PortasAbertas {
  int i;
  int n;

  PortasAbertas({this.i, this.n});

  PortasAbertas fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.i = json['i'];
    this.n = json['n'];
    return this;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'i': i,
      'n': n
      };
  }
}

/*Aqui é como você irá utilizar a sua classe*/
void main() {
  var jsonData = '[{"i":737,"n":1}]';
  var parsedJson = json.decode(jsonData);
  
  dynamic portasAbertas = parsedJson.map((value){
    return value;
  }).toList();

  PortasAbertas objeto = PortasAbertas();
  objeto.fromJson(portasAbertas[0]);
  print('I = ${objeto.i}');
  print('N = ${objeto.n}');
}
```

Obs.: Você pode rodar este exemplo aqui neste [site](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) e ver como funciona.

***Explicação***

Peguei o seu JSON, quebrei ele em uma lista de `Map<String, dynamic>` que vai possuir todos os objetos do seu JSONArray.
Depois peguei a posição 0 da sua lista e joguei em sua classe.

Comment: Isso mesmo, na minha resposta deixei alguns outros exemplos também, como por exemplo converter uma data para um campo do tipo DateTime

Answer (score 1):

Parafraseando [este meu artigo](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/n%C3%A3o-use-drogas-use-flutter-talk-2-671ad7c19c30) (se quiser ler inteiro contém um exemplo completo de deserialização de json):

> Se pararmos para analisar, qualquer estrutura Json é basicamente um
>   Map de chave/valor, por isso é exatamente assim que ele é representado
>   em Dart. Na linha 8 criamos o construtor fromJson que vamos utilizar
>   para ‘deserializar’ o json, ou seja, transformar para um Objeto, por
>   isso ele recebe um Map de String(a chave será sempre string) e
>   dynamic, que para Dart é como se fosse um tipo genérico, qualquer tipo
>   pode estar em uma variável do tipo dinâmico.

Basicamente toda 'chave' do Map que representa o Json é uma `String`, assim como todo valor é a princípio um `dynamic`. Você está tratando a chave como `int`, então mude para `String`:

```dart
PortasAbertas.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  i = json['i'];
  n = json['n'];
}
```

O processo de 'serialização' funciona igual, também utilizando `String`:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  return {
    'i':i,
    'n':n
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria dessa forma então para deserializar ?

```
class PortasAbertas {
  int i;
  int n;

  PortasAbertas({this.i, this.n});

  PortasAbertas.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    i = json['i'];
    n = json['n'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'i': i,
      'n': n
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas apenas uma informação, implemente isso em sua pergunta, editando a mesma! Não é legal você responder a sua pergunta com uma outra pergunta!
A forma como você tinha comentado minha resposta estava mais correta...

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica

Comment: Agora como faço para pegar o vetor ?
eu estava fazendo assim :  NumeroPortas objeto = new NumeroPortas.fromJson(responseJson);
      _msg = ('Numero total de portas: ${objeto.numerodeportas}'); mas para pegar json sem vetor, com vetor ainda não sei como fazer

Comment: Verifique a edição da minha resposta e qualquer dúvida, utilize a seção de comentários da minha resposta.